# Why is the client side rendered virtual dom tree not matching server-rendered content when using this?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, nuxt.js, vue-router

The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content. This is likely caused by incorrect HTML markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside p, or missing tbody. Bailing hydration and performing full client-side render.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>
            Any text
        </p>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import Vue from 'vue'


export default {

}
</script>
```

When i remove everything inside the div it wont error.

**What i did**

I just added vue router for a simple router guard. To access the page you need to login the redirection works fine and i get no errors, but when i change my url to https://my-website/ingelogd i get the **login page** shown and a second later the **logged in** page is shown. And then i get the error message, but i don't understand why. Can someone help me out?

Comment: When I render your example, I don't get the error, so I think this example is maybe too simplified. Could you add more code?

Comment: Thank you for responding @CollinAllen problem fixed. The problem was that firebase authentication runs before vue and thinks for a second that i am actually logged out while i was logged in.

Comment: @user10004588 how did you solve this?